# Traffic source issue in GA4 with subfolders

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have established 2 properties from 2 different accounts in ga4 for tracking our website general English root domain `example.com` in the first property and tracking its subfolder `example.com/es/` in the second. GTM container is single, there are 2 different ga4 config tags having such trigger conditions: first has Page URL doesn't contains `/e`s for tracking root domain pages and events, and second Page URL contains `/es` for subfolder.

When a user changes language version of the website, e.g. moves from the page `example.com/business` to `example.com/es/business`, GA4 always starts new session in the second GA4 property with direct traffic source. Although client id of this user persists and this user can come to `example.com/business` from paid or organic search before. So there is a loss in traffic source and how it can be solved? Both data streams for these 2 properties have main domain included in the List of unwanted referrals, but if we remove it from this list I assume that we'll have self-referral issue for users that move to and from subfolder and main domain.

In addition tried to explore similar user's path in Universal Analytics as we have the same configuration with 2 different account/properties in UA. So in this case traffic source doesn't change, I think because client id is the same and it depend on it in UA rather than in ga4. All this path and client id is shown in the User Explorer report of UA.